# Passing information between threads (foreach with %dopar%)

Tags: r, foreach, cluster-computing, snow

I'm using doSNOW- package for parallelizing tasks, which differ in length. When one thread is finished, I want

- some information generated by old threads passed to the next thread
- start the next thread immediatly (loadbalancing like in clusterApplyLB)

It works in singlethreaded (see makeClust(**spec = 1** ))

```
#Register Snow and doSNOW
require(doSNOW)

#CHANGE spec to 4 or more, to see what my problem is
registerDoSNOW(cl <- makeCluster(spec=1,type="SOCK",outfile=""))

numbersProcessed <- c() # init processed vector
x <- foreach(i = 1:10,.export=numbersProcessed)  %dopar% {

    #Do working stuff
    cat(format(Sys.time(), "%X"),": ","Starting",i,"(Numbers processed so far:",numbersProcessed, ")\n")
    Sys.sleep(time=i)

    #Appends this number to general vector
    numbersProcessed <- append(numbersProcessed,i)

    cat(format(Sys.time(), "%X"),": ","Ending",i,"\n")
    cat("--------------------\n")
}

#End it all
stopCluster(cl)
```

Now change the spec in "makeCluster" to 4. Output is something like this:

```
[..]
Type: EXEC 
18:12:21 :  Starting 9 (Numbers processed so far: 1 5 )
18:12:23 :  Ending 6 
--------------------
Type: EXEC 
18:12:23 :  Starting 10 (Numbers processed so far: 2 6 )
18:12:25 :  Ending 7
```

At 18:12:21 thread 9 knew, that thread 1 and 5 have been processed. 2 seconds later thread 6 ends. The next thread has to know at least about 1, 5 and 6, right?. But thread 10 only knows about 6 and 2.

I realized, this has to do something with the cores specified in makeCluster. 9 knows about 1, 5 and 9 (1 + 4 + 4), 10 knows about 2,6 and 10 (2 + 4 + 4).

Is there a better way to pass "processed" stuff to further generations of threads?

Bonuspoints: Is there a way to "print" to the master- node in parallel processing, without having these "Type: EXEC" etc messages from the snow package? :)

Thanks!
Marc

Comment: You haven't understood how a `foreach` loop works. It's not a `for` loop. Read the `foreach` package vignette to learn how to combine the results into one object (btw. growing an object, e.g., using `append` in a loop, is one of the cardinal performance sins in R). AFAIK, you can only do fully independent (embarrassingly parallel) tasks in parallel with `foreach`.

Comment: @Roland I thought about something like this: The "main" program spawns n worker threads. When 1 of them is finished, the main program fetches the results, maybe makes a little postprocessing (printing to the console about the progress, manipulating global variables, etc) and spawns a new one. I don't think thats a very uncommon use-case. I already knew, that the first n threads won't have information about the others (because they are running while the new one is spawning). In my case it would be sufficient to have all data availabe at the time when the new process spawns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Damn.

I thought, foreach with %dopar% **is** load-balanced. **This isn't the case**, and makes my question absolete, because there can nothing be executed on the host-side while parallel processing. That explains why global variables are only manipulated on the client side and never reach the host.